# CGO library build to JS WASM file

Tags: go, webassembly, cgo

I wanna write JS script using webassembly library builded from Golang.
But I need to use C library and use it through CGO.

In short my code looks like this (just example of loading C libraries):

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    println("Hello")
}
```

But when I wanna build it as in tutorial with command bellow I have error.

Command:

```
GOARCH=wasm GOOS=js go build -o lib.wasm test.go
```

Output:

```
can't load package: package main: build constraints exclude all Go files in [Project path]
```

So my question is more if it's even possible to build something like this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That won't fly: `GOARCH=wasm GOOS=js` basically makes the Go compiler to produce *wasm bytecode* from the *Go source.* To spell this in other words, the Go code gets compiled to WASM bytecode and the WASM API calls instead of CPU-specific machine code and system calls to a particular OS kernel.

On the other hand, `cgo` is a way to *link* the *compiled* C code with the *compiled* Go code. To compile a program making use of `cgo`, the `go` toolchain calls out to a real C compiler (`gcc` most of the time), which compiles the C parts.

Compiled C code and WASM bytecode exist in different universes and do not know about each other. In theory, a C compiler such as `gcc` could have a WASM backed—just like `go` has now—but IIRC this is neither the case nor the Go's WASM backend is taught to somehow handle such a case.

All-in-all, the most typical case for using `cgo` is interfacing with an already existing library written in C (or exposing a C-compatible API), and most of such libraries usually make profound assumptions about the environment they run in—which typically is a POSIX-compatible OS (with a set of syscalls to handle file and socket I/O and so on).

Hence if you are in a rare position of having the need to link with a "pure" C library—which performs pure data processing and does not communicate with an underlying OS in any way, it might be possible to look at a C-to-Go source-code translator.

Comment: I'd note that the WASM backend for GCC [might materialize, eventually](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2017-03/msg00044.html).

Comment: Uhh, the whole point of web assembly is that you can compile native languages like C into it.
There are PLENTY of use cases linking Go WASM to a C WASM library.
For Go to be taken seriously as a WASM language, it something that should be done.
The `llgo` frontend for `llvm` is likely where it'll happen first.

Comment: @Zv_oDD, please calm down and try to re-read the question (and my answer). If we were to flesh out the bare minimum from the question, it was like "why does Go compiler not compile (or transpile or whatever) my C code to WASM target?". The essence of my answer is that the Go compiler only compiles Go code, and has limited support for making that compiled Go code interoperate with C—with the help of a C compiler. To put is as simple as possible: the Go compiler does not compile C.

Comment: @Zv_oDD, so your complaints are misdirected: the fact WASM should be produced by any higher-level programming lanuage is not disputable, but the Go toolchain produces WASM from Go source code, not C. Some tooling, in theory, could possibly somehow "glue together" WASM "objects" produced by compilers of various HLLs, but as long as we're talking about Go tooling, it's not there yet—basically that should be not `cgo` then but `wasmgo` or some such. To require from the Go toolchain to be able to also compile C to WASM is a bit of a stretch—no matter whether you dislike this or not.

Comment: @Zv_oDD, in the end, what's the point of venting in a thread of an answer of an obscure SO question? If you feel like you want Go to have such support (compile C to WASM) please go ahead and [file an issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/) instead.

Comment: I just disagree with your point about it being a rare use case or there not being many pure C libraries out there. There are a bunch of pure C libraries that are used in popular Go packages with CGO. Many of those with their C backing library having examples of being compiled to WASM, but cannot be used in Go WASM builds currently - as far as I can figure.
Considering how popular CGO is in go libraries and how WASM is gaining a lot of traction I really do think the Go community would benefit from a solution. Not sure if it should be part of mainline Go?

Sorry, I didn't mean any offense.

Comment: I do think it's an important point to address because I came here looking for the answer to the main question of this SO thread "Is it possible to build something like this?". It's worth pointing out that there is a `llvm` front-end that might make it possible (`llgo`) sooner than a theoretical Golang feature that hasn't even been discussed on the main "mailing list" yet.

Comment: https://github.com/therecipe/qt uses cgo to create Go bindings for Qt. It successfully compiles to WASM and runs in the browser. This suggests to me that what the OP is after is possible.