# How to compile an amd64 binary that uses C on an M1 (arm64) Mac

Tags: go, go-build

My app compiles fine when `GOARCH` is set to `arm64` (or is omitted). However, when I try to compile an amd64 binary (`GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build`), I get the following error:

```
package [mainPackage]
        imports [internalPackageThatUsesC]: build constraints exclude all Go files in [pathToInternalPackageThatUsesC]
```

`[internalPackageThatUsesC]` consists of 3 files – an Objective C file with the implementation, a header for it and a Go file which provides an interface for the native code. Following is the Go file:

```golang
// +build darwin

package [internalPackageThatUsesC]

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -x objective-c
#cgo LDFLAGS: -framework Cocoa

#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include "[headerFile].h"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "sync"
    "unsafe"
)

... public functions that use the C library to interact with the native code
```

Names annotated with `[]` mean they are a placeholder for the actual name.

I tried to run it with `arch -x86_64` but the output is the same.

What's the problem here? Do I need to add another build tag?

P.S. I found questions on StackOverflow about this error but none of them were about compiling for amd64. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946214/cgo-library-build-to-js-wasm-file) question was the closest but it was WebAssembly-specific.

Following is the result of `go env`:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="arm64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/fperson/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/fperson/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/fperson/.asdf/installs/golang/1.16.4/packages/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/fperson/.asdf/installs/golang/1.16.4/packages"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/Users/fperson/.asdf/installs/golang/1.16.4/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/Users/fperson/.asdf/installs/golang/1.16.4/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.4"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/fperson/workspace/personal_projects/timeow/timeow-mac/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch arm64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/mh/02gmkb756x15018g919jcg980000gn/T/go-build4031963624=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, I also needed to set `CGO_ENABLED` to true. The app now compiles fine for amd64 with `GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 go build`

(Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69258229/9714875) answer)

Comment: Congrats! I will update my answer to point to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer to the wasm question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54946750/225692) (as you posted) talks about cgo. cgo invokes platform compiler with platform specific headers/libs (on Mac, with framework too). When you cross-compile with `CC`, you also need cross-compile compiler + headers/libs + frameworks. It is not easy: you may need tools like [xgo](https://github.com/karalabe/xgo). But still cross-compile may fail.

Go is different, Go re-implements a HAL in go or plan9 ASM on each OS/arch. So when you cross-compile cgo + go for am64 on arm64 together, <strike>`go build` will try to blend "cgo+arm64" with "go+amd64". Sadly, it is an empty set for the built-in `go build` tool.</strike>

Refer to the @fperson's [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70483079/225692).

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! I'll try to use `xgo`

Comment: Oh, I was just able to compile it with `CGO_ENABLED=1`! 